# unresolved reference: [BigInteger].longValue

Tags: kotlin, biginteger

The Kotlin code

```
import java.math.BigInteger
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(BigInteger("1").longValue())
}
```

produces the compile error `unresolved reference: longValue` (dito for `intValue`). Other methods of BigInteger like `modInverse` are found without any issue. Unless there's a typo I'm not seeing, I'm rather stumped here as to why this is happening ...

Comment: Use toLong(). https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-number/index.html

Comment: Thanks, that did it. How is it possible though that Kotlin supresses a public method of a Java class?

Comment: I don't know exactly how they do it, but I know they do to unify/sanitize the API. For example, String.split() takes a Regex instead of a String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, you can use `.toLong()` and `.toInt()`. In addition, there's also `longValueExact()` and `intValueExact()`.

`.toLong()` actually resolves to `longValue()` (CTRL+click in IntelliJ), so it looks like it's done to conform with language standards.